# AttributeError when filling empty list with strings

Tags: python, list, loops, attributeerror

I currently have a list

```
outcomes = [('A','B','C','A.B','A.C','B.C','A.B.C')]
```

and I am trying to loop over it. If one of the "name" in the list contains a A, then I want to create another list called column_names with that name in it. 
For instance, if I am looking for As, my returning list would be:

```
column_names = ['A','A.B','A.C',A.B.C']
```

I have the following code:

```
column_names = []
for name in outcomes:
    if 'A' in name:
        column_names = column_names.append(name)
```

but it returns:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I checked and both column_names and outcomes are lists so I dont understand why.

Comment: append does not return a new list: it modifies the list in-place.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list=list()
 for i in outcomes:
    for j in i:
        if   j.count('A') == 1: 
            my_list.append(j)
```

output:

```
['A', 'A.B', 'A.C', 'A.B.C']
```

in your code 
you used  `column_names = column_names.append(name)` you must use `column_names.append(name)` instead